# Parallel processing in angular 2 to speed up processing

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to split a for-loop processing into 4 parallel for-loops to fasten the processing speed.
How can i achieve it in angular2/typescript?

Comment: Please provide some code to demonstrate your train of though or to simply show your progress so far. We can't do your work sadly.

Comment: Your question is currently too broad. You do not explain the kind of task that you wish to parallelize, nor what you have tried so far. The fact that you are using Angular and/or TypeScript might not even be relevant.

Comment: what kind of task you want to archive?

Comment: You couldn't fasten processing speed, as JS engine is single threaded. Using `Observables`, `Promises` or `timeouts` you can defer completion of your loops, but it wouldn't fasten anything. You can just make all loops complete approximately at the same time. However, if you are talking about template syntax `*ngFor`, than indeed you can speedup processing, by at least running your code outside Angular.

Answer (score 1):

You can use WebWorkers to utilize more CPUs, otherwise there is no way, because the UI thread only utilizes a single CPU and no async execution will change that.

See also

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers
- http://www.htmlgoodies.com/html5/tutorials/introducing-html-5-web-workers-bringing-multi-threading-to-javascript.html